# How to listen to all CSSDOM changes using js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom, dom-events

I have this js code which changes the visibility of body tag to hidden and then makes it visible after 5seconds by disabling a style tag.

```js
var style = document.createElement('style');
style.id='xyz';
style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(''));
document.head.appendChild(style);
style.sheet.insertRule('body { visibility: hidden }', 0);
setTimeout(()=> {
  console.log('-----here after 3secs-----',style.sheet.disabled) 
},3000);
setTimeout(()=>{ 
  console.log('--------here after 5secs-------');style.sheet.disabled=true;
},5000);
setTimeout(()=>{ 
  console.log('-----here after 10secs-----',style.sheet.disabled)
},10000);
```

I am trying to listen to this change using `mutationObserver`.

```js
var mutationObserver = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
   mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
      console.log("log-",mutation);
   });
});
mutationObserver.observe(document.documentElement, {
      attributes: true,
      characterData: true,
      childList: true,
      subtree: true,
      attributeOldValue: true,
      characterDataOldValue: true
});
```

But this does not show any log.
So is there any way to detect this change in dom. (using `cssdom` changes maybe but I am not able to find any such).

Comment: Why are you looking to detect a change in the DOM? It seems like depending on your actual goal there might be a better way to accomplish it

Comment: I want to detect all the changes in a particular website that does this operation related to visibility change ... I just want to detect this operation and do some action based on it.
The problem is mutationObserver is unable to do so.